# Bootstrap dividers and selection

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my code to appear like the image given below, but I couldnt fix it.I used bootstrap.
1) When I hover, I want a full length white box to appear like given in the image but only a fixed width and height in grey appears
2) The height of the line doesnt not exceed more than that, I want the first vertical line to merge with second one

```css
.row.vdivide [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}
.row.vdivide1 [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:5;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}
.row.vdivide2 [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}

hr{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
#one:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
<div class="container sf-category">
      <div class="row vdivide">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h4 id="one">Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide1">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h4 id="one">Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide2">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h4 id="one">Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide3">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h4 id="one">Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide4">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h4 id="one">Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

IMAGE : [image]

Editing-image: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A whole new approach (to resemble the picture given):

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<p>
BROWSE JOBS BY ROLE
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 01
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 02
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 03
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 04
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 05
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 06
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 07
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 08
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 09
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 10
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 11
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 12
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 13
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 14
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 15
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 16
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 17
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 18
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
  background: #35b084;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px;
}

.col-sm-2 {
  border-right: 1px solid #78ccae;
}
.col-sm-2:last-child{
  border-right: none;
}
hr{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  border-color:#78ccae;
}
.container{
  margin:10px 0px;
}
.col-sm-2:hover{
  background:white;
  color:#35b084;
}
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8anLsL/

Hope this is what you wanted!

EDIT:

To get 5 rows (as shown in your picture) use this code:

HTML:

```
<div class="main">
<p>
BROWSE JOBS BY ROLE
</p>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 01
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 02
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 03
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 04
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 05
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 06
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 07
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 08
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 09
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 10
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 11
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 12
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 13
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 14
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 15
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 16
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 17
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 18
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 19
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 20
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 21
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 22
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 23
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 24
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 25
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 26
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 27
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 28
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 29
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <span class="container">
      test 30
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8anLsL/1/

Another Fiddle using also fontawesome icons: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8anLsL/2/

One more edit is to replace all classes named "container" to another name (since class container is a regular bootstrap class). Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/3w8anLsL/3/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot

Comment: I need to use only 5 rows but the line on the right is extended, i will share the picture of it. @captain theo

Comment: @prathanadan Sorry for the late reply -due to time difference! I have edited my answer to include 5 rows.

Answer (score 1):

Use `id="one"` to the column and `display:flex` to the row class.

**working example**

```css
.row.vdivide [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}
.row.vdivide1 [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:5;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}
.row.vdivide2 [class*='col-']:not(:last-child):after {
  background: #d9534f;
  width: 1px;
  content: "";
  display:block;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100%;
 
}

hr{
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 2%;
}
#one:hover{
    background-color: #eee;
}
.row-eq-height {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/></head>
<body>
       <div class="container sf-category">
      <div class="row vdivide row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"  id="one"><h4>Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide1 row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" id="two"><h4>Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide2 row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" id="three"><h4>Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide3 row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" id="four"><h4 >Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    <hr style="background-color: #d9534f">
      <div class="row vdivide4 row-eq-height">
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center" id="five"><h4>Software Developer</h4></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>2</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>3</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>4</h1></div>
      <div class="col-sm-2 text-center"><h1>5</h1></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: An id of same value cannot be used multiple times in the dom. Consider changing it to "class"!